# Prestashop voucher system

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

The problem I am having is related to voucher codes.
By default, Prestashop will apply a discount of a particular product to the total of the entire cart. For example, if I have 3 products in my cart, all priced at £100, the total sum of the cart is £300.
If i have a voucher for a total value of £200 that is valid for only 1 of the 3 products in my cart, the behavior I want to achieve is that Prestashop will recognise that the voucher is valid for only one product, and rather than deducting the £200 voucher total from the cart total (essentially applying the remainder of voucher credit to the other two, non applicable items), it will deduct only the amount of all applicable items (in this case, £100), and some how create a new voucher for the remainder of the credit.

Hopefully this makes sense and many thanks in advance for any help offered.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it now is to create a new category (hidden), place the product in there (in addition to the current place), and assign the voucher to the new category.

[Source](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/142854-voucher-for-one-product-only/)

Comment: Problem being there will be hundreds of vouchers each month. Seems like a lot more manual work having to create categories for individual products :(

Comment: @IanLeckey What if you created a single hidden category for all voucher-valid products, and just created all of your vouchers to be only valid for that category?

For example:
You create the (hidden) category "Voucher Products."
When creating or editing a product to use a voucher, you add that product to its usual category, along with "Voucher Products." Then, you create the voucher only for "Voucher Products." This way, you can create as many vouchers as you want while still streamlining the  creation and management process.

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop, you can create a voucher for an individual category, but not yet for a specific product. At this point, product-specific vouchers would require changes to the code in several different places. As mentioned in Narek's source link, this is something the PrestaShop team is working on for a future release, but that functionality is not currently available in the default installation of PrestaShop.

Source: I am PrestaShop's [Community Manager](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/user/276528-mike-kranzler/)